# How to drag and drop figures from palette into GEF editor?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

I am working on GEF project.In that project I want to drag and drop figures from palette into GEF editor. I tried by adding some listeners but still I am not able to drag and drop.

**This is my code:**

```
public class OPMGraphicalEditor extends GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette {

private Resource opdResource;
private ObjectProcessDiagram opd;

public OPMGraphicalEditor() {
    setEditDomain(new DefaultEditDomain(this));
}


@Override
protected PaletteViewerProvider createPaletteViewerProvider() {
    return new PaletteViewerProvider(getEditDomain()) {
        @Override
        protected void configurePaletteViewer(PaletteViewer viewer) {
            super.configurePaletteViewer(viewer);
            viewer.addDragSourceListener(new TemplateTransferDragSourceListener(
                    viewer));
        }
    };
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private TransferDropTargetListener createTransferDropTargetListener() {
    return new TemplateTransferDropTargetListener(getGraphicalViewer()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected CreationFactory getFactory(Object template) {
            return new NodeCreationFactory((Class<OPMObject>) template, getModel());
        }

        private Object getModel() {

            return null;
        }
    };
}


@Override protected void initializeGraphicalViewer() {
    GraphicalViewer viewer = getGraphicalViewer();
    super.initializeGraphicalViewer();
    getGraphicalViewer().setContents(opd);
    getPaletteViewerProvider().getEditDomain().getPaletteViewer().addDragSourceListener(
            new TemplateTransferDragSourceListener(getPaletteViewerProvider().getEditDomain().getPaletteViewer()));

    // listen for dropped parts
    viewer.addDropTargetListener(createTransferDropTargetListener());
}

@Override
protected void setGraphicalViewer(GraphicalViewer viewer) {
    super.setGraphicalViewer(viewer);
    this.getGraphicalViewer().addDropTargetListener(new TemplateTransferDropTargetListener(getGraphicalViewer()));

}

@Override protected void configureGraphicalViewer() {
    super.configureGraphicalViewer();
    getGraphicalViewer().setEditPartFactory(new OPMEditPartFactory());
}


@Override
protected PaletteRoot getPaletteRoot() {
    PaletteRoot palette = new PaletteRoot();
    Activator activator = Activator.getDefault();
    IWorkbench workbench = activator.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    ISelectionService selectionService = workbenchWindow
            .getSelectionService();
    ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();
    return new OPMGraphicalEditorPalette();

}

@Override public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    if(opdResource == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        opdResource.save(null);
    } catch(IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        opdResource = null;
    }
}

@Override public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    super.init(site, input);

    loadInput(input);
}

private void loadInput(IEditorInput input) {
    OpmPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass(); // This initializes the OPMPackage singleton implementation.
    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    if(input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
        IFileEditorInput fileInput = (IFileEditorInput) input;
        IFile file = fileInput.getFile();
        opdResource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(file.getLocationURI().toString()));
        try {
            opdResource.load(null);
            ObjectProcessDiagram opd = (ObjectProcessDiagram) opdResource.getContents().get(0);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            opdResource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things:

1. Add a target drop target listener to your graphical viewer: `getGraphicalViewer().addDropTargetListener(new TemplateTransferDropTargetListener(getGraphicalViewer()));`
2. Add a drag source listener listener to the palette: 
   `getEditDomain().getPaletteViewer().addDragSourceListener(
   new TemplateTransferDragSourceListener(getEditDomain().getPaletteViewer()));`
3. change your creation tools to `CombinedTemplateCreationEntry`

A more thorough explanation can be found in the [blog post I created for the occasion](http://www.vainolo.com/2013/02/06/creating-an-opm-gef-editor-part-23-drag-drop-from-the-palette/)

Comment: I tried out by adding these 3 things u have mentioned above...But still its not working.I really not getting what is the reason.Its not generating any figures on Editor.Its not displaying any figures.I tried by taking your code only from your tutorials..Can you please tel me what may be the problem